# Can I use Jest's expect() outside .spec.ts in NestJS?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I want to do integration tests without actually mocking anything.
I use test db and scripts to put all example data to all entities and then I want to run tests on this data.

Now I want to use jest's expect() function inside special testing service working as an ordinary Nest service. And just trigger controller to see what happening during the whole workflow.

Can I do that?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. It's usually more standard to make something like that a `spec.ts` file still and put it in a describe block. I've never used `expect` outside a `test/it` callback, so you may need a little bit of extra work if it doesn't work off the bat

Comment: As @JayMcDoniel indicated, you can do this in standard `spec.ts` files, and just do not add the mocks.  This is also preferred, as the `spec.ts` does not get built into your production version, so there is no bloat or extra tests running then.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

"expect" is now available as a standalone module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect

With this, you can use the jest-matchers in your special testing service.
Failures will throw Errors that are visualized and understood by jest in the same way jest visualizes errors caused by expect()-failures in the test-code itself.